# Selecting a 3gb file, submit action triggers, over 3gb submit action no longer works

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Really stumped here why this is not working...

I have a input and a button that I use to get a file path to later do some work with. The issue that I am having is that if I pick a ~3gb file, my submit action work as as expected. If I pick a ~4gb or ~5gb file my submit action no longer works. Nothing is going back to the server. I do not do an upload. Im just using the filepath selected. Any idea what is going on? This is using IE.

UPDATE: This works in Chrome but since I cant get the path correctly my functionality fails.

Code for file selection:

```
 public CmtMediaUiGenerator<TModel> video(
            Expression<Func<TModel, MediaFileViewModel>> fileExpression,
            Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> widescreenExpression,
            Expression<Func<TModel, int?>> formatExpression,
            Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> encryptedExpression = null,
            bool stacked = false,
            object htmlAttributes = null)
        {
            string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
            MvcHtmlString label = HtmlHelper.LabelFor(fileExpression, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "label" });

            //MvcHtmlString id = HtmlHelper.IdFor(expression);
            StringBuilder validationMessages = new StringBuilder();
            validationMessages.Append(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(fileExpression).ToHtmlString());
            validationMessages.Append(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(widescreenExpression).ToHtmlString());
            validationMessages.Append(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(formatExpression).ToHtmlString());

            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            html.AppendFormat("<div class=\"video-container\" id=\"{0}\">", id);

            html.Append("<div class=\"video-file-container\">");

            string fileId = HtmlHelper.IdFor(fileExpression).ToHtmlString();
            MediaFileViewModel fileValue = fileExpression.Compile().Invoke(Model);
            html.AppendFormat("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{0}.FilePath\" name=\"{0}.FilePath\" value=\"{2}\" />"
                + "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{0}.MediaFileId\" name=\"{0}.MediaFileId\" value=\"{3}\" />"
                + "<button id=\"{0}-button\" class=\"button button-small\">Select File</button>"
                + "<span id=\"{0}-value\" class=\"display-value file-name-display\">{1}</span>",
                fileId,
                (fileValue == null ? null : Path.GetFileName(fileValue.FilePath)),
                (fileValue == null ? null : fileValue.FilePath),
                (fileValue == null ? 0 : fileValue.MediaFileId));

            html.Append("</div>");
            html.Append("<div>");

            string widescreenId = HtmlHelper.IdFor(widescreenExpression).ToHtmlString();
            bool widescreenValue = widescreenExpression.Compile().Invoke(Model);
            html.AppendFormat("<div class=\"checkbox-value\">"
                + "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"true\" disabled {1} />"
                + "<label for=\"{0}\">Widescreen</label>"
                + "</div>",
                widescreenId, (widescreenValue ? "checked" : ""));

            string formatId = HtmlHelper.IdFor(formatExpression).ToHtmlString();
            int? formatValue = formatExpression.Compile().Invoke(Model);
            html.AppendFormat("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\" />"
                + "<div class=\"label\">Format:</div><span id=\"{0}-value\" class=\"format-value\">{2}</span>",
                formatId, formatValue,
                (formatValue == null ? "n/a" : string.Format("MPEG {0}", formatValue)));

            string encryptedId = (encryptedExpression == null ? null
                : HtmlHelper.IdFor(encryptedExpression).ToHtmlString());
            if (encryptedExpression != null)
            {
                bool encryptedValue = encryptedExpression.Compile().Invoke(Model);
                html.AppendFormat("<div class=\"checkbox-value\">"
                + "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\" value=\"true\" disabled {1} />"
                    + "<label for=\"{0}\">Encrypted</label>"
                    + "</div>",
                    encryptedId, (encryptedValue ? "checked" : ""));

                validationMessages.Append(HtmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(encryptedExpression).ToHtmlString());
            }
            html.Append("</div>");

            html.AppendFormat("<script>$(function() {{ setUpVideoUpload('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}); }});</script>",
                id,
                fileId,
                widescreenId,
                formatId,
                (encryptedId == null ? "null" : "'" + encryptedId + "'"));
            html.Append("</div>");

            GenerateEditItemSet(id, label.ToHtmlString(), html.ToString(), validationMessages.ToString(),
                stacked: stacked,
                valueCssClass: "file-value");
            return (this);

            //new string[] { "1", "2", "4" }
        }
```

Submit:

```
public CmtMediaUiGenerator<TModel> saveCancelButtons()
        {
            Output.Append("<hr />"
                + "<p>"
                    + "<a href=\"/Media/\" class=\"button\">Cancel</a>"
                    + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"PostAction\" value=\"Save\" class=\"button button-primary\" />"
                    + "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"PostAction\" value=\"Save & Close\" class=\"button button-primary\" />"
                + "</p>");
            return (this);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So this looks like it might be related the the browser and limiting uploads to 4gb at a cap.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the answer to my problem

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/wininet-internet-explorer-file-download-and-upload-maximum-size-limits.aspx